# How does the begin/async tcplistener work

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, service, tcplistener

I am creating a windows service that accepts TCP connections, processes data sent to the server, then returns back a message saying the process is complete. There are several clients that will be connecting to the service and that number is growing. To handle these messages, I thought that using a non-blocking structure would be ideal. From initial searches, the `BeginAcceptTcpClient` appeared to be what I was looking for. I was looking [at this tutorial](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3081443/application-development/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-socket-in-c.html) to get a sample, but I have a few questions on how this works. My code I have based on this example is below.

1. In the `OnClientConnected` function, why is it necessary to call `WaitForClients` again? Why doesn't the listener just always listen?
2. What happens if another connection is attempted before `WaitForClients` is called again? I know it is the first statement in the `OnClientConnected`, but there could be two connections that happen "at the same  time"
3. I can't really understand how this works in terms of multithreading. If I had 10 simulations connections, it looks like the first one will enter `OnClientConnected`, then call `WaitForClients`, which will then allow another connection to be handled. This seems sort of a one connection at a time approach rather than having several threads that can handle lots of traffic.

---

```
public class DeviceListener
{
    private TcpListener listener = null;

    public DeviceListener()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(1001);
    }

    public void StartListener()
    {
        listener.Start();
        //TODO: Log listening started here
        WaitForClients();
    }

    private void WaitForClients()
    {
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnClientConnected, null);
    }

    private void OnClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        WaitForClients();
        TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);

        if(client != null)
        {
            //TODO: Log connected
            HandleClientRequest(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientRequest(TcpClient client)
    {
        //Code to process client request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, it accepts exactly as many connections as `BeginAcceptTcpClient` calls, so in order to accept another one you need to call `BeginAcceptTcpClient` again. Beginning of handler seems like a reasonable place to do so.
2. It will be queued and handled with next call to `BeginAcceptTcpClient` or timed out if that doesn't happen in timely manner.
3. [Please refer to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm), these are most likely run using `ThreadPool`.